# Wand object Color creation very slow

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I have a numpy pixels array and I want transform it to a TIFF image, but the object Color creation is very slow; for an array/image size of 1280x2440 it takes about 4 minutes to create a Wand Image with pixel assignment. Sample code:

```
# print a.pixel_array.shape
#  (1280, 2440)

with Image( width = a.pixel_array.shape[ 1 ], height = a.pixel_array.shape[ 0 ] ) as i1:
    i1.type = 'grayscale'
    i1.format = 'tiff'
    i1.compression = 'undefined'
    i1.resolution = ( 300, 300 )
    i1.alpha_channel = False

    for idxy, y in enumerate( a.pixel_array ):
        for idxx, x in enumerate( y ):
            hex_color = hex( x )[ 2: ].zfill( 4 )
            with Color( '#' + hex_color + hex_color + hex_color ) as color:
                i1[ idxx, idxy ] = color
```

Is the process of creating the Color object intrinsically slow or is there some faster implementation to carry out the same procedure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Image.import_pixels`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.6/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.import_pixels) method to import all pixels at once.

```py
import numpy as np
from wand.image import Image

pixel_array = np.random.randint(255, size=(1280, 2440), dtype='u1')

with Image(width=pixel_array.shape[0],
           height=pixel_array.shape[1]) as i1:
    i1.type = 'grayscale'
    i1.format = 'tiff'
    i1.compression = 'undefined'
    i1.resolution = ( 300, 300 )
    i1.alpha_channel = False
    i1.import_pixels(width=pixel_array.shape[0],
                     height=pixel_array.shape[1],
                     channel_map='I',
                     storage='char',
                     data=pixel_array.flatten().tolist())
```

Note that the array data type is an unsigned char (color values between 0 ~ 255).

Comment: Wow, now it takes less than 1 second for the image transformation!